# System crash during apt install

Tags: 18.04, apt, crash

I was trying to `apt install chromium-browser` and for some minutes it worked fine but then everything froze. I went to the server room and found that the machine was now offline. The syslog only shows these weird symbols:

```
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
```

What could've caused this?

Answer (score 0):

Which might cause this problem is Antivirus. If you are running any Antivirus disable it temporarily until installation complete then re-enable Antivirus again.

If solution didn't solved try installing Chromium from Snap Store which won't have this problem.

Comment: Don't have any antivirus software installed

Comment: @Acqua Try installing Chromium from Snap Store.

Comment: @Acqua Here is link : https://snapcraft.io/chromium